# Ubuntu Error: failure reading sector 0x100800 from 'hd0'

Tags: ubuntu, grub, bootsector

My laptop freezed, so I restarted my system manually, and ended with the **Grub** terminal. I tried running the **ls** command in Grub terminal and got the result as

```
grub> ls

(hd0) (hd0, gpt2) (hd0,gpt) error: failure reading sector 0x100800 from 'hd0'.
error: failure reading sector 0x100800 from 'hd0'.
```

I am unsure whether the OS crashed or some problem with my SDD. Can someone help me on that ?

Comment: Edit your question in proper way and search for solution before asking here

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248138/error-failure-reading-sector-0x802-from-hd0-entering-rescue-mode-grub-rescue